# Container Height for Listview and Gridview

Tags: flutter

Both Listview and Gridview needs `height` to be shown into our app.
But each model of phone has different size as height so it is impossible to define static height of the parent container of the list.

What I need to put as height for the container once use listview and gridview to cover all the phone model ?

Code:

```
Container(
  height: 500,
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: 20,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => showDialog(
          context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            actions: [
              Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
              Text(widget.user.name),
            ],
          )
        ),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          child: Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

in this specific case height is 500 and it is good for some mobile phone but for other no, please let me know.

Comment: Do you want only `listView` or `gridView` in the entire screen?

Comment: both because I have the same problem with both

Comment: ok, i've understood your problem

Comment: So, where are you using this `listView` and `gridView`? In a new screen or in a screen with other widgets?

Comment: I use gridview and listview into a screen with other widgets

Comment: Then you have to provide a specific `height`. You can provide some demo images of your app so that I'll get a rough idea of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: If I provide a specifi height as my code above, it might work on some mobile but in other I can get or a empty space below.. or overflow..

Comment: If you're using `column` then you will get empty space or overflow, instead of that use `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223933/discussion-between-hardik-kumar-and-tizi-dev).

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen height width for make it responsive according to devices:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1 //It takes 1 of 10 proportion of screen height
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width* 0.2 //It takes 2 of 10 proportion of screen width
```

Comment: yes, use the proportion that matches, it is just an example

Answer (score 0):

You can place your `GridView` or `ListView` inside `Expanded` widget. The `Expanded` widget will take all the available space & you can easily show your `GridView` or `ListView` widget.

This solution will work on multiple screen sizes also without any problem because it will occupy the available space on its own.

```
Column(
    children: [

    // Any other widget

    Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => showDialog(
                context: context, builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  actions: [
                    Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
                    Text(widget.user.name),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 5,
                child: Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
    ),

    // Any other widget

  ],
),
```